# NLog, ASP.NET Core and SQL - The server was not found or was not accessible

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, nlog

I've been trying to get an ASP.NET Core site working with NLog. It works fine until I try to write to a SQL Database. I've tried local databases and Azure databases - all with the same problem. I've even added the nlog table to a known database, one the site already connects to (with EF).

I'm using the nuget package: NLog.Web.AspNetCore

No matter what, I get the following:

> Error Error when writing to database. Exception:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections.

Here is how I am configuring things (I have tried changing the order of these statements):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
            loggerFactory.AddNLog();
            app.AddNLogWeb();
            env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
            LogManager.Configuration.Variables["connectionString"] = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
//etc...
```

Here is my nlog config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Warn"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">

  <!-- define various log targets -->
  <targets>
    <target name="db"
            xsi:type="Database"
            commandType="StoredProcedure"
            commandText="[dbo].[NLog_AddEntry_p]">
      <parameter name="@machineName"    layout="${machinename}" />
      <parameter name="@siteName"       layout="${iis-site-name}" />
      <parameter name="@logged"         layout="${date}" />
      <parameter name="@level"          layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@username"       layout="${aspnet-user-identity}" />
      <parameter name="@message"        layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@logger"         layout="${logger}" />
      <parameter name="@properties"     layout="${all-event-properties:separator=|}" />
      <parameter name="@serverName"     layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_NAME}" />
      <parameter name="@port"           layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_PORT}" />
      <parameter name="@url"            layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTP_URL}" />
      <parameter name="@https"          layout="${when:inner=1:when='${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTPS}' == 'on'}${when:inner=0:when='${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTPS}' != 'on'}" />
      <parameter name="@serverAddress"  layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=LOCAL_ADDR}" />
      <parameter name="@remoteAddress"  layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_ADDR}:${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_PORT}" />
      <parameter name="@callSite"       layout="${callsite}" />
      <parameter name="@exception"      layout="${exception:tostring}" />
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="db" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Last, here is my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\projectsV13;Database=XXXX;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't using the variable "connectionString" in your db target.

You also need

```xml
<target name="db"
   .. 
   connectionString="${var:connectionString}"
>
```

Variables in NLog are not automatically bound to a target. You need to set and use them in your config.

**update**

Since NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.8 (NLog.Extensions.Logging 1.4 for .NET Core console programs) you could directly read from your appSettings.json

```xml
<target name="db"
   .. 
   connectionString="${configsetting:name=ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection}"
>
```

see [docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer)

Comment: That's right @Julian. I had read somewhere that using the connection string in the target was broken. So instead I was using this:LogManager.Configuration.Variables["connectionString"] = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");   I'll try again with the data in the Target node within nlog config.

Comment: well you still need `LogManager.Configuration.Variables["connectionString"] = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");` - you need both (config and C#)

Comment: Both? Ok I will try that! I'll update here after I test.

Comment: YES That was it. I needed both the variable set to the connection string, and then use that variable in the config. In hindsight it makes perfect sense. Thanks for the help @Julian

Comment: yeah! I think the warning message in NLog would be nice ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's several years later.  I ran into this same problem.  NLog doesn't like the backslash in Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database...

I got around it using a variable in nlog.config:

```
<variable name="connStr" value= "${configsetting:name=ConnectionStrings.MyConnection}" />

<target 
    xsi:type="Database"
    name="databaseLog"
    connectionString="${connStr}"
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all,

ConnectionString is look like different

if you are using Local, you can take this error. But if you have a server 
define code is like this.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {  "DatabaseContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=NAME;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"}
```

In my opinion: The second reason about error. Maybe you can not read correctly to connectionString.

Comment: Thanks @aemre. I've tried some different connection strings but no luck. The format you suggest, with the providerName attribute is not valid for ASP.NET Core appSettings.json file.

Comment: Okey @AndySchwam , when i answered this question there was no CORE. So sorry about this.  This link may help you  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration